# Using the React.js Virtual DOM to mock a canvas on Node.js

Tags: node.js, canvas, reactjs

I'm trying to mock the canvas in Node.js using the virtual DOM in the React.js framework but I'm having trouble finding out how to create a canvas element and access the canvasContext.

I want to be able to create a new canvas object, get the context and draw a few lines.

This is what I've figured out so far (after npm install react)

```
>var DOM = require('react').DOM;
undefined
>var canvas = DOM.canvas();
undefined
>canvas
{ props: { __owner__: null },
  _lifeCycleState: 'UNMOUNTED',
  _pendingProps: null,
  _pendingCallbacks: null }
```

Is there somewhere else that I should be creating the canvas and how can I access the canvas context?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about how you're trying to use React and canvas together?

Comment: I'm running a javascript application on Node.js (no canvas) and wanted to use some libraries that run in the browser and write to canvas to generate images. I was hoping to create those images in React's virtual DOM's implementation of canvas. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, React doesn't do anything special with canvas -- it simply defers to the browser for all the drawing stuff.

You might want to use something like https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas instead for server rendering of canvas code.

Comment: So does it cache the canvas draw instructions to execute later on the browser or is it just not possible to call any draw instructions?

Comment: The latter -- it gives a `componentDidMount` hook within which you can do your drawing but otherwise doesn't do anything fancy.